# iOS Regex: Unknown escape sequence "\|"

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm getting a weird warning, and as a result my regex search isn't working. Here's the line:

```
NSRange r = [HTML rangeOfString:@"\|(.*)\|" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
```

Where `HTML` is a string that I'm sure contains a single match for the above regex.

The warning is only on the first occurrence of "\|", not on both.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You're getting the warning because `\|` is not a valid escape sequence in Objective-C (or C or C++ for that matter).  The compiler is ignoring that and just using a raw `|` character instead, so the string you're actually passing in is `@"|(.*)|"`.

To get the behavior you want, you have to escape the backslash in your source code so that the regex engine sees the literal backslash and interprets the `|` character as a literal instead of as alternation, e.g. `@"\\|(.*)\\|"`.

Comment: Follow up question: Let's say I was matching that to a string like "|adsfsad| asdfsadf |" and I only want to catch the first one ("|asdfsad|") instead of it matching the entire string, how can I specify that?

Comment: You can use "\\|(.*?)\\|" to catch the first one ("|asdfsad|")

Answer (score 0):

Just to add up, if you are dealing with special character sequences in unicode format, you can use something like this:

```
const unichar specialCharSequence='some special character';
if(specialCharSequence==L'\uxxxx')
{
   //handle the occurence of this special character
}
```